# Count the frequency of list element in a row grouped by Date and tag

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, metadata

I have a dataframe df which looks like this:

```
ID       Date        Input
   1         1-Nov       A,B
   1         2-NOV       A
   2         3-NOV       A,B,C
   2         4-NOV       B,D
```

i want my output to count the occurrence of each input, if it is consecutive otherwise reset it to zero again(if IDs are same then only count) , Also the output should be renamed to X.A, X.B, X.C and X.D so my output will look like this:

```
ID      Date       Input      X.A      X.B      X.C      X.D
   1       1-NOV      A,B        1      1      0      0
   1       2-NOV      A          2      0      0      0
   2       3-NOV      A,B,C      1      1      1      0
   2       4-NOV      B,D        0      2      0      1
```

How can I create the output(A,B,C and D) which will count the input occurence date and ID wise.

Comment: How working my solution?

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, solution is  working as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) for indicator columns and then count consecutive `1` per groups - so use [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html) with subtract by [`GroupBy.ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ffill.html), change columns names by [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) and last [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original:

```
a = df['Input'].str.get_dummies(',') == 1
b = a.groupby(df.ID).cumsum().astype(int)
df1 = (b-b.mask(a).groupby(df.ID).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)).add_prefix('X.')

df = df.join(df1)
print (df)
   ID   Date  Input  X.A  X.B  X.C  X.D
0   1  1-Nov    A,B    1    1    0    0
1   1  2-NOV      A    2    0    0    0
2   2  3-NOV  A,B,C    1    1    1    0
3   2  4-NOV    B,D    0    2    0    1
```

Answer (score 1):

first add the counts of new columns and then use group by to make a cumulative sum

```
# find which columns to add
cols = set([l for sublist in df['Input'].apply(lambda x: x.split(',')).values for l in sublist])

# add the new columns
for col in cols:
    df['X.' + col] = df['Input'].apply(lambda x: int(col in x))

# group by and add cumulative sum conditional it has a positive value
group = df.groupby('ID')
for col in cols:
    df['X.' + col] = group['X.' + col].apply(lambda x: np.cumsum(x) * (x > 0).astype(int))
```

results is then

```
print(df)
   ID   Date  Input  X.C  X.D  X.A  X.B
0   1  1-NOV    A,B    0    0    1    1
1   1  2-NOV      A    0    0    2    0
2   2  3-NOV  A,B,C    1    0    1    1
3   2  4-NOV    B,D    0    1    0    2
```